# Append to an array of a nested element in jq but return root object

Tags: json, jq

My json looks like this:

```json
{
  "routing": {
    "rules": [{
      "type": "field",
      "inboundTag": ["input"],
      "outboundTag": "vpn-out"
    },{
      "type": "field",
      "inboundTag": ["alternate"],
      "outboundTag": "raw-out"
    }]
  }
}
```

I want to append to the `.routing.rules[].inboundTag` array where the `outboundTag` has the value of "vpn-out". At the same time I want the modified root object returned so that I can save it into a bash variable.

So far I have:

```sh
  config=$(echo "$config" | jq \
    --arg out_tag "$outbound_tag" \
    --arg in_tag "$inbound_tag" \
    '.routing.rules[] | select(.outboundTag==$out_tag) | .inboundTag += [$in_tag]')
```

The problem is that the `select`ed object is returned rather than the root object. How can I modify the code to return the root?

[Here is a jq-play link](https://jqplay.org/s/uNtAiHhWhj)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to only mark "that" desired object for update, ways you can do that would be to use below which selects the update to be performed from the standpoint of the rootnode.

```
( .routing.rules[] | 
 select(.outboundTag==$out_tag) | .inboundTag ) += [$in_tag]
```

One other way would be to use the update assignment operator `|=`, to select the object under `rules` containing your outbound tag and append to its `inboundTag`

```
.routing.rules |= ( map(select(.outboundTag==$out_tag).inboundTag += [$in_tag]  ) )
```

Comment: Used your example to figure it out, while at the same time you modified your answer. Thanks for the help. This jq is easy until you want to do complicated things.